Semme a Cardiff you go there!

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. Compelling bishop to inhabit obscure valley (10)
6. Common pets with friendly personality and large muscles (4)
9. A little out of Cardiff, a namesake place of a famous cheese that has been visited by Queen Elizabeth (10)
10. Place to enjoy some Joe Cocker initially misled me (4)
12. Infiltrating Nazi group, I stumble slightly, advertising Ford vehicles (7)
13/26. A god that's happy to be a social media figure (7,7)
14. Euro court has detained everyone in connection with another case (8)
17. Small leaves regularly lost in lifts (6)
19. European had consumed a little cellulose and broke it down (6)
21. European parliamentarian joining evacuation (8)
26. (See 13 across)
28/33. Foreign agent calls to Spooner; they're not the most natural couple (7,10)
30. Action requested after disappearance of teacher? (4)
31. Doctor in science department's lead describes multiple occurrences (10)
32. Degree acquired by Samuel, a Nigerian prince? (4)
33. (See 28 across)
Down
1. Request inexperienced reporter to come up with cutting-edge tool? (7)
2. Lord, for one, captivated by fairy tale (5)
3. Marketplaces in Pomerania in disarray as Austrian on vacation goes missing (7)
4. Renaissance poet Mario's torturing bears (7)
5. A cold stream's surface carries little purple flowers (6)
7. Amazement surrounds a king showing up (5)
8. Cases the woman has picked up at hospital (7)
11. Bring together elements of government in kingdom after uprising (4)
15. Program loses power in office network, possibly (3, abbr.)
16. Like Mao's little book recited on the radio (3)
17. Undermine simpleton (3)
18. Tropical vacation spot deported black man with Arabic name (3)
19. Regiment ultimately abandons German officers-to-be for a long time (7)
20. Has Romantic poet started too late? (4)
22. Mike mounting a strong and large dog (7)
23. North Carolinian's heart broken on train (3,4)
24. Facilitates atmospheric components getting on (7)
25. UEFA member's soccer team has controlled the final in style (6)
27. East Siberian runner is Amy and Ketanji's coworker (5)
29. Hamburger's after a slice of onion and a single chip (5)

A rather tough but fun challenge with some inventive clueing and even more inventive definitions. I can't find a Nina or hidden theme, but that doesn't really mean anything. :)
Across

 1. BELIEVABLE (compelling) = B (bishop in chess) in BELIE (obscure, as verb) VALE (valley)
 6. LABS (common pets with friendly personality) = L (large) + ABS (muscles)
 9. CAERPHILLY (&lit, a Welsh cheese) = ER (Elizabeth Regina) in C (a little out of Cardiff) + A + PHILLY (Philadelphia, also a kind of cheese)
 10. CAFE (place to enjoy some Joe / coffee) = C "misleads", i.e. is the wrong lead for (j)AFE (me, the poster of this puzzle)
 12. SIERRAS (Ford vehicles) = I ERR (I stumble) + A (slightly, advertising) in SS (Nazi group)
 13/26. CONTENT CREATOR (A god that's happy; social media figure)
 14. WALLAROO (euro) = ALL (everyone) + A(nothe)R (another case) in W.OO (court, v.)
 17. STEALS (lifts) = S (small) + TEA (leaves) + L(o)S(t) (regularly lost)
 19. DANCED (broke it down, i.e. danced breakdown, I guess) = C (a little cellulose) in DANE'D (European had)
 21. EMPTYING (evacuation) = E (European) + MP (Member of Parliament) + TYING (joining)
 28/33. STRANGE BEDFELLOWS (not the most natural couple) = STRANGE (foreign) + Spoonerism of FED (agent) BELLOWS (calls)
 30. DEED (action) = DE(sir)ED (requested) − SIR (teacher)
 31. INCIDENCES (multiple occurrences) = Anagram (doctor) of IN SCIENCE D (department's lead)
 32. SCAM (a Nigerian prince, asking for money by e-mail) = C (degree Celsius) in S.AM

Down

 1. BUCKSAW (cutting-edge tool) = ASK (request) + CUB (inexperienced reporter), all reversed (to come up) + W (with)
 2. LIEGE (Lord) = EG (for one, i.e. for example) in LI.E (fairy tale)
 3. EMPORIA (marketplaces) = anagram (in disarray) of POMER(an)ia missing A(ustria)N (Austrian on vacation)
 4. ARIOSTO (Renaissance poet) hidden in (bears) M(ARIO'S TO)rturing
 5. LILACS (purple flowers) = LI'L (little) + A + C (cold, as on a water tap) + S (stream's surface)
 7. AWARE (showing up) = A + K (king, in chess or card games) in AW.E (amazement)
 8. SHEATHS (cases) = AT H (at hospital) in SHE'S (the woman has)
 11. KNIT (bring together) hidden backwards in (elements of ... uprising) governmen(T IN K)ingdom
 15. LAN (office network, possibly) = (p)LAN (program) − P (power in physics)
 16. RED (like Mao's little book), sounds like (on the radio) READ (recited)
 17. SAP (undermine; simpleton)
 18. ALI (man with Arabic name) = (b)ALI (tropical vacation spot) − B (black, pencil grade)
 19. DECADES (a long time) = DE (German, ISO language code) + CADE(t)S (officers-to-be) − T (Regiment ultimately)
 20. EATS (has) = (k)EATS (Romantic poet) minus first letter (started too late)
 22. MASTIFF (large dog) = M (Mike, NATO alphabet) + A + STIFF (strong, like a drink)
 23. TAR HEEL (North Carolinian, nickname) = anagram (broken) of HEART + EL (train, elevated railway)
 24. GREASES (facilitates) = RE (on, as regards) in G.ASES (atmospheric components)
 25. FRANCE (UEFA member) = RAN (controlled, i.e. managed a shop etc.) in FC (soccer team, common abbr. for football club) + E (final in style)
 27. ELENA (Kagan, co-member of Amy Coney Barrett and Ketanji Brown Jackson of the U.S. Supreme Court) = E (east) + LENA (Siberian "runner", i.e. river)
 29. NACHO (single chip) = NACH (Hamburger's after, after in German) + O (slice of onion)

Grid

 


I don't see 30a -- rot13(vs lbh gnxr FVER sebz QRFVERQ lbh trg QRQ abg QRRQ, naq V qba'g frr gung FVE zrnaf sngure). I wonder whether it's just an error, or whether I'm missing something.

Good point. I didn't see the missing letter. I guess I'm missing something here, but rot13(ZNAQ qbrfa'g zrna sngure rvgure).

Rot13(FVE (nf bar zvtug erfcrpgshyyl nqqerff bar'f sngure) vafgrnq bs FVER jbexf)

You misspelled rot13(ORQSRYYBJF) in the solutions.

@Someone: "Strange" is an angram indicator, of course. (Have fixed it. I've also changed "sire" to "sir" while keeping a straight face. I'm not really convinced.)

@GarethMcCaughan Augh, right, that's a dumb error on my part. It's supposed to be rot13(qrfverq zvahf fver) and somehow I didn't see there's a letter missing. Sorry about that!

You could fix this by rot13(znxvat gur "sngure" n "grnpure") without breaking the clue.

@MOehm Good idea, done
